# Get my user's information using MS Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get my information using the Graph API SDK for C# (the idea is the application running without user interaction), as shows code sample below:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("xxx")
    .WithTenantId("xxx")
    .WithClientSecret("xxx")
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);


GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.DisplayName,
        u.Mail,
        u.UserPrincipalName
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

It's returning 'WaitingForActivation' on Status, I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Could you share more code? It would be benefical to share a method where you call graphClient.Me.Request(). The issue is related to async/await not Graph API

Comment: @user2250152, the method is being requested from an API test, It's something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not like you think. If you call the `/me` endpoint, you must log in the user. It actually obtains the logged-in user information, so you cannot use the **client credential flow** to obtain the access token.  For the client credential flow, it is usually used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background and do not interact with the user immediately(No user logged in).  For the `/me` endpoint, it needs to accept the user token, because it has user interaction. So, I suggest you use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get access token,which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

[Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider):

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
```

---

By the way, if you want to get user information in a scenario where no user is logged in, you can call the `/users` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("xxx")
    .WithTenantId("xxx")
    .WithClientSecret("xxx")
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);


GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var user = await graphClient.Users["{userId or userPrincipalName}"].Request()
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.DisplayName,
        u.Mail,
        u.UserPrincipalName
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your answer, I'll try your suggestion. - 

- How can I get my '{userId or userPrincipalName}'? 

- Its possible get users userId list of users aren't my contacts or that Id's list from my contacts?

Comment: @AdrianoMarquesGonalvesdosS  This is very simple, you have two ways to get the user userId or userPrincipalName. 1. Go to Azure portal>AAD>Users>All users https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwssH.png. 2. Request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to get all user information.  User id is the id in your contact list.

Comment: I'm getting using the Graph Explorer with the default sample account, apparently all is great, but when I sign in with my account, I can't request the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/presence for example, show me Bad Request (400), do I need to enable anything on my account?